# The character I created doesn't come back to the exact platform after a single trigger press on UP arrow key

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am a Pygame beginner. I started to build a game on jumping dinosaur. The character I created doesn't come back to the exact platform after a single trigger press on UP arrow key. It lands slightly above the platform and its lands perfectly after 2,3 UP arrow presses.

I am a complete beginner.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))


x = 20
y = 400
width = 30
height = 45
vel = 10
black = (0,0,0)

x1 = 20
y1 = 30

white = (255,255,255)


run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    win.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x>=20:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]and x<=450:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y>=20:
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y<=390:
        y += vel
    #gravity
    else:
        if not keys[pygame.K_UP] and y <= 400:
            y += 30

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.draw.line(win,white,[0,472],[472,472],2)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gravity application is broken. There is plenty of ways to fix this, my choice here is to always apply gravity but limit y so that it can never go bigger than the height of the character above the ground-plane.

To elaborate on what's actually wrong with your approach: your jumps create upwards motion incremented by `vel`. Which is only a fraction of `gravity`. So pushing the character up e.g. 40 pixels, and then pull it down by 30 pixels leaves you 10 pixels above ground. Only if you manage to precisely rise exactly a multiple of `gravity`, you will fall back.

My solution always falls down but then limits the position to the one where the character is right on the ground level.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))


x = 20
y = 400
width = 30
height = 45
black = (0,0,0)

x1 = 20
y1 = 30

white = (255,255,255)

bottom = 472
gravity = 30
vel = 10 + gravity

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    win.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x>=20:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]and x<=450:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y>=20:
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y<=390:
        y += vel

    else:
        y = min(bottom - height, y + gravity)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.draw.line(win,white,[0,bottom],[bottom,bottom],2)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks...never thought that I will get the answer this fast..thank you

Comment: You can accept it if you want, that will give me the full points awarded.